# Write command removing quotes and adding them at random

Tags: string, python-2.7, file, text

So I am programming in python 2.7 and I am trying to copy a text file line by line so that I can modify a few lines and save as a new file. I have everything working except the output file has a whole bunch of quotes(") removed and added? This is what one original line looks like:

```
"IECKAI"            TurbModel       - Turbulence model ("IECKAI"=Kaimal, "IECVKM"=von Karman, "GP_LLJ", "NWTCUP", "SMOOTH", "WF_UPW", "WF_07D", "WF_14D", "TIDAL", or "NONE")
```

When I run

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\bhansen\\Desktop\\TestEnv\\TurbSim2.inp', 'r')
NewInputFile = open('C:\\Users\\bhansen\\Desktop\\TestEnv\\MyInput.inp', 'wb')
for i in range(0, 66):
    line = f.readline()
    if i == 31:
        num, stf = line.split(" ", 1)
        num = '9'
        new_line = num + stf
        NewInputFile.write(new_line)

    elif i == 36:
        num, stf = line.split(' ', 1)
        num = '8'
        new_line = num + stf
        NewInputFile.write(new_line)        

    else:
        NewInputFile.write(line)
```

it gets written to the new file like this

```
"IECKAI            TurbModel       - Turbulence model ""(""""IECKAI""""=Kaimal,"" IECVKM=von Karman, GP_LLJ, NWTCUP, SMOOTH, WF_UPW, WF_07D, WF_14D, TIDAL, or NONE)"
```

Why is it going this and how do I fix it?

P.S. the given line was line 30 of the text file but it also does the same thing for the if statement lines

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. After sending the source code and input file to someone else we found that for some reason (only this machine) didn't like reading from a .inp file. So we changed the read in file to a .txt file type but left the output file as a .inp (which it had to be for the program it was being passed to) and it worked just fine.